# Challenge in scraping elements in URL, perhaps due to javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, python-requests-html

I'm trying to scrape the following soccer match betting odds from this [website](https://online.singaporepools.com/en/sports/competition/66/football/france/french-league).

I realised that the elements I'm looking for in the URL are not available in the returned source and hence I can't capture them with BeautifulSoup.

My subsequent searches led me to believe that this is due to the javascript rendering of DOM. I tried a couple of approaches - `Selenium` and also `requests_html`. Both did not seem to work. The code (below) I used for `requests_html` seemed to run fine but I still get the same old result of the source page. Can someone guide me on what might be the reason? Has it nothing to do with the javascript rendering?

### `requests_html` code below

```py
session = AsyncHTMLSession()

r = await session.get('https://online.singaporepools.com/en/sports/competition/66/football/france/french-league')
await r.html.arender()

P_html = r.text
P_soup = BeautifulSoup(P_html, "html.parser")
```

Comment: Where do you get `P_html` from?

Comment: That's just a feature/variable I created to hold the text of the html. Do I need to declare something first? I tried printing the parsed html and it printed fine - it just didn't print the parts that I want...